# Use Android phone as bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I am looking to use my android phone (samsung galaxy s5) as a bluetooth keyboard.  Is my phone even capable of emitting a findable bluetooth signal which could be picked up by another device such as a laptop iPad or even another android, the same way which a normal bluetooth keyboard would work?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not functionality that standard Android phones have. While it's not outside of the realm of possibility for a manufacturer to add this functionality, I've never heard of it being done.